# I want to remove numbers from the_posts_pagination function

Tags: pagination, navigation

I am not good in editing theme codes especially with wordpress but I tried to on my own to edit the pagination in my theme archive.php which include numbers (1,2...10) and next/prev links.

```
<?php

    global $wp_version;

    if ( $wp_version >= 4.1 ) :

        the_posts_pagination( array( 'mid_size'  => 0, 'prev_text' => __( 'Previous', 'Ht' ), 'next_text' => __( 'Next', 'Ht' ) ) );
    
    endif;

?>
```

I want to removed the numbers to display only Next/pervious link but I tried alter the code but the numbers still displays. I don't know how I can possibly remove the number from display.